# How to get Android Volley StringRequest GET to return responses in UTF-8 encoding

Tags: android, utf-8, android-volley

How can I get Android Volley StringRequest GET to return responses in UTF-8 encoding? It only seems to return responses in ISO-8859-1.

Is it possible to get it to accept a UTF-8 string?

Comment: Many, many, thanks for the quick replies. Simply added   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');  in my PHP file on the server before echoing the string.

Answer (score 0):

StringRequest call HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers) to get charset from response headers, is 'Content-Type' in headers don`t contains 'charset' the default charset return as 'ISO-8859-1'.

StringRequest.java

```
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    String parsed;
    try {
        parsed = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException var4) {
        parsed = new String(response.data);
    }

    return Response.success(parsed, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
}
```

HttpHeaderParser.java

```
public static String parseCharset(Map<String, String> headers, String defaultCharset) {
    String contentType = headers.get(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE);
    if (contentType != null) {
        String[] params = contentType.split(";");
        for (int i = 1; i < params.length; i++) {
            String[] pair = params[i].trim().split("=");
            if (pair.length == 2) {
                if (pair[0].equals("charset")) {
                    return pair[1];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return defaultCharset;
}

/**
 * Returns the charset specified in the Content-Type of this header,
 * or the HTTP default (ISO-8859-1) if none can be found.
 */
public static String parseCharset(Map<String, String> headers) {
    return parseCharset(headers, HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
}
```

so, you can parse to 'UTF-8' in 2 ways:

1. tell your webServer to add 'Content-Type' with 'charset=UTF-8' in headers
2. Create a subclass of StringRequest and override parseNetworkResponse method

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert text from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8, but this is slow!

```
    byte[] utf8 = new String(volleyResponse, "ISO-8859-1").getBytes("UTF-8");
    volleyResponse = new String(utf8);
```